# Transformation of the operators $\mathbf\nabla$ and $\partial/\partial t$ under Galilean transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, inertial-frames, coordinate-systems, galilean-relativity

I want to know how are the transformations of the operators $\mathbf\nabla$ and $\partial/\partial t$ when the transformation of the Galilean relativity is applied.

**This is what I've tried:**

***Galilean Transformation***
\begin{cases}
 \mathbf {r}' = \mathbf r - \mathbf Vt \\
  t'=t
\end{cases}

The "total differential" operator can be written like this
$$ d=\partial_xdx+\partial_ydy+\partial_zdz+\partial_tdt$$
or more compactly

\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:d_operator_K}
   d=\mathbf\nabla\cdot d\mathbf r +\partial_tdt
 \end{equation}
Since $\mathbf r=\mathbf r'+\mathbf Vt$, then

\begin{align*}
   d\mathbf r & = d\mathbf r' + d(\mathbf V t) \\
              & = d\mathbf r' + t\,d\mathbf V + V\,dt  
 \end{align*}
The velocity $\mathbf V$ is constant, so the differential $d\mathbf V$$ is zero.

\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:diferentials}
   \begin{cases}
     d\mathbf r = d\mathbf r' + \mathbf V dt \\
     dt=dt'
   \end{cases}
 \end{equation}
Substituting the differential above into the total differential operator, gives

\begin{align}
   \label{eq:d_operator}
   d &= \mathbf\nabla\cdot \left(d\mathbf r' + \mathbf V dt\right) +\partial_t dt \\
     & = \mathbf\nabla\cdot d\mathbf r' + \left(\mathbf V dt +\partial_t\right)dt
 \end{align}
The same $d$ operator, in terms of the moving coordinate system is written like this
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:d_operator_KK}
   d=\mathbf\nabla'\cdot d\mathbf r +\partial_{t'}dt'
 \end{equation}

**Here is the doubt**
I think the operators $d$, no matter in which coordinete system are written, must to be equals. So I can match coefficients and get this
$$\mathbf\nabla'\cdot d\mathbf r +\partial_{t'}dt=\mathbf\nabla\cdot d\mathbf r' + \left(\mathbf V dt +\partial_t\right)dt$$
\begin{equation}
   \boxed{
     \begin{aligned}
    \mathbf\nabla' &=\mathbf\nabla \\
   \partial_{t'}=&\mathbf\nabla + \mathbf V \partial_t
 \end{aligned}
 }
 \end{equation}

Can you tell me whether my argument is right or wrong?

And can you tell me some references where I can take a look about this topic?

Comment: Your second equation in the box is clearly wrong as a scalar quantity is set equal to a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$
   \nabla'\cdot d{\bf r'}+dt'\partial_{t'}=\nabla\cdot(d{\bf r}+{\bf V}dt)+dt\partial_t = \nabla\cdot d{\bf r}+(\partial_t+{\bf V}\cdot\nabla)dt
$$
and you get the Euler time derivative as it should.

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right, I didn't applied properly the distributive property. Do you know any references about this topic?

Comment: I think a classical one is the Goldstein's book https://books.google.it/books?id=bhVnngEACAAJ&dq=goldstein+classical+mechanics&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7s9Lby6DZAhXFBSwKHXXtCWQQ6AEIKDAA